# Meteor UX Issue: After adding item to a sorted list, the item is added to the top and then sorted

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am creating a basic chat with Meteor.

On the client I do:

```
div.chat-discussion
  each messages
    +chatMessage
```

The helper is

```
Messages.find
   conversationId: t.data.conversation._id
,   
   sort:
      createdAt: 1
```

So I am sorting the chat message in order from oldest first to newest last.

The chat looks like this

[image]

But whenever I send a message, it isn't added directly to the bottom.

It is added to the top for a few milliseconds and then shifted to the bottom.

It makes the UX feel glitchy. Why is this happening, and how can I fix this?

**UPDATE**

I seemed to have fixed the issue by removing the sort and just returning the messages in the helpers like

```
Messages.find
   conversationId: t.data.conversation._id
```

So if I don't sort client side, the message is added to the bottom of the message list automatically without flashing. I am not sure how or why. I guess by default it is sorted in order of oldest first.

Comment: Interesting issue. Your solution would be better posted as an answer, but may be inconsistent across browsers. Could you create a MeteorPad to show this?

Comment: How are you setting the created at value on the conversation item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was happening.

The problem in the end was a conflict with the sorting I was using and how the timestampable (https://atmospherejs.com/zimme/collection-timestampable) package adds the createdAt field.

I was sorting on the client by the field createdAt, which is added by the timestampable package. The issue is that the field doesn't exist when the document is first inserted, so that is why I saw the message append to the top of the list and when the `createdAt` field got added right after, then it jumped down to its sort position.

To fix this I am adding a field called `sentAt` upon insertion, and now also sorting by that field.

This fixed the issue. I was trying to sort by a field that did not exist upon insertion. This will show itself in the UI even if the field is added right after insertion.

Answer (score 1):

There is no default sort on a collection other than FIFO which means as long as you do not sort, the records are send as they were written.

If you just have continously messages, this may fit your needs, but when you are in sync / offline situations sometimes, you might get the list not as it is when time sorted.

I guess you are using `autopublish` on server?

You should write your own server `publish` method and return the sorted list already from server.

So on client you may subscribe then just by `find()` or do also the sort on mini-mongo (preferred)

This should prevent glitchy UX

Cheers

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the answer. I was not using autopublish. I actually figured it out and will post my answer.

Comment: Hi @nearpoint, you did not wrote that you used an own publish method nor that using that timestampable package. I really might not believe that you need that additional `sentAt` field. Have you saved you collection to `/lib` ? Normally that field should be already set on miniMongo side.